# Email form data to user's email

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms, email

i am trying to email what the submitter filles out in the textarea to him after her clicks the "Submit" button.
the "current_user" is a wordpress codex that takes the logged-in user's email.

my code does print out the correct email + what i fill out in the textarea,
but it does not send it to this email.
i don't know what to fix.
thanks for your help!

```
<form action="#" method="post">
<textarea  name="lesson1"></textarea><br>
 <input type="submit" name="Send" value="Send to your Email" />
</form>
 </div>

 <?php
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
 $email = $current_user->user_email;
 $lesson1 = htmlspecialchars($_POST['lesson1']);
echo $lesson1, $email;
$email_subject = "Test E-Mail (This is the subject of the E-Mail)";
(mail($email, $email_subject, $lesson1);
if(mail($email, $email_subject, $lesson1)){
echo "The email($email_subject) was successfully sent.";
} else {
echo "The email($email_subject) was NOT sent.";
?>
```

Comment: why you use a txtarea? you could use a email input field

Comment: Can you not use an email input. Then use PHP to grab the email

Comment: hey, thank you. my textarea is not getting an email adress, i get it from wordpress database. my textarea is supposed to be the body of my email message. how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You have opened the else block but never closed it  in below part:

```
} else {
   echo "The email($email_subject) was NOT sent.";
?>
```

Also, you have an extra line before the if condition as below. If this is not used, comment it.

```
(mail($email, $email_subject, $lesson1);
```

Comment: thank you very much. but it is still not sending the email :( its just printing out the email address, the textarea and "the email was not sent"... :(

Comment: @Sharon - in that case, you'll need to check your mailserver error logs to find out the issue. You do have a mailserver installed on the machine where this code is running, don't you?

Comment: i'm really sorry for being a newbie..i am using wordpress. do i need to add anything to have a mailserver?

Comment: I think you should go to admin panel and edit mail server SMTP settings